# Dividing two variables returns 0

Tags: ruby

When I set it up so `ratio = needed / count` the function works but I need a percentage so when I set it up as `ratio = count / needed` it should then theoretically give back a decimal point, but it's returning 0. What am I doing wrong? I need it to give back the correct number to set the width percent.

```
  def percent_bar(piece, options={})
    count = file.total_count
    needed = HD::Application.config.files_needed
    ratio = count / needed
    percent = ratio * 100
    s = "<div class='progress'>"
    s += "<div class='progress-bar' role='progressbar' aria-valuemax='#{needed}' aria-valuenow='#{count}' aria-valuemin='0' style='width: #{ratio}%;'>"
    s += "<span class='sr-only'>#{count} of #{needed}</span>"
    s += "</div>"
    s += "</div>"

    return s

  end
```

Comment: Please, read about variable types and how they affect the operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dividing two Integer values so result will always be an Integer.

Do this instead:

```
count / needed.to_f
```

Example:

```
count = 1
needed = 2
count / needed
# => 0
count / needed.to_f # type conversion to float
# => 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because integer division is being performed. Use `to_f` to convert to `float`.

`ratio = count/needed.to_f`